# Use multiple root namespaces when deserializing with .NET XmlSerializer

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

My question is very much like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435260/use-multiple-namespaces-when-deserializing-with-net-xmlserializer). However, I need to allow two different namespaces on the same root.

Something like:

```
    [XmlType(Namespace = "")]
[XmlRoot("included_parameters", Namespace = "http://apif.freescale.net/schemas/paramdef/1.0")]
[XmlRoot("included_parameters", Namespace = "http://apif.freescale.net/schemas/paramdef/1.1")]
public class IncludedParameters
{
}
```

So basically, I want to deserialize an xml file for version 1.0 of the schema ot 1.1 of the schema into the same .net class.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Chris

Comment: Don't include namespace : [XmlRoot("included_parameters")]

Comment: @jdweng - if I remove the Namespace attribute, Deserialize throws an exception saying <included_parameters xmlns='http://apif.freescale.net/schemas/paramdef/1.0'> was not expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `SerializationBinder` class that let one do this kind of type conversion operation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
"Some users need to control which class to load, either because the class has moved between assemblies or a different version of the class is required on the server and client"
```