# XML Serializer/Deserialize With Multiple Classes

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to convert an XML document well actually a CXML Document to an object.

First of all here is the XML document as a class, 
I used [this site](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/) as When I did it with 
`Special Paste` from following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document) thread, the code that was generated was quite messy.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
public class Order
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Credential")]
    public class Credential
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Identity")]
        public string Identity { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "domain")]
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SharedSecret")]
        public string SharedSecret { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "From")]
    public class From
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Credential")]
        public Credential Credential { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "To")]
    public class To
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Credential")]
        public Credential Credential { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sender")]
    public class Sender
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Credential")]
        public Credential Credential { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UserAgent")]
        public string UserAgent { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Header")]
    public class Header
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "From")]
        public From From { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "To")]
        public To To { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sender")]
        public Sender Sender { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Money")]
    public class Money
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "currency")]
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Total")]
    public class Total
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Money")]
        public Money Money { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Name")]
    public class Name
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Country")]
    public class Country
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "isoCountryCode")]
        public string IsoCountryCode { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "PostalAddress")]
    public class PostalAddress
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DeliverTo")]
        public string DeliverTo { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Street")]
        public List<string> Street { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "State")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PostalCode")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Country")]
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CountryCode")]
    public class CountryCode
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "isoCountryCode")]
        public string IsoCountryCode { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TelephoneNumber")]
    public class TelephoneNumber
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CountryCode")]
        public CountryCode CountryCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AreaOrCityCode")]
        public string AreaOrCityCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Phone")]
    public class Phone
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TelephoneNumber")]
        public TelephoneNumber TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Fax")]
    public class Fax
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TelephoneNumber")]
        public TelephoneNumber TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Address")]
    public class Address
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
        public Name Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PostalAddress")]
        public PostalAddress PostalAddress { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Phone")]
        public Phone Phone { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fax")]
        public Fax Fax { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "addressID")]
        public string AddressID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "isoCountryCode")]
        public string IsoCountryCode { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ShipTo")]
    public class ShipTo
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Address")]
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BillTo")]
    public class BillTo
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Address")]
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Description")]
    public class Description
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ShortName")]
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Shipping")]
    public class Shipping
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Money")]
        public Money Money { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description")]
        public Description Description { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "trackingDomain")]
        public string TrackingDomain { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "trackingId")]
        public string TrackingId { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TaxableAmount")]
    public class TaxableAmount
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Money")]
        public Money Money { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TaxAmount")]
    public class TaxAmount
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Money")]
        public Money Money { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TaxDetail")]
    public class TaxDetail
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TaxableAmount")]
        public TaxableAmount TaxableAmount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TaxAmount")]
        public TaxAmount TaxAmount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description")]
        public Description Description { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "percentageRate")]
        public string PercentageRate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "purpose")]
        public string Purpose { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Tax")]
    public class Tax
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Money")]
        public Money Money { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description")]
        public Description Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TaxDetail")]
        public TaxDetail TaxDetail { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DiscountPercent")]
    public class DiscountPercent
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "percent")]
        public string Percent { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Discount")]
    public class Discount
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DiscountPercent")]
        public DiscountPercent DiscountPercent { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "PaymentTerm")]
    public class PaymentTerm
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Discount")]
        public Discount Discount { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "payInNumberOfDays")]
        public string PayInNumberOfDays { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Comments")]
    public class Comments
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Extrinsic")]
    public class Extrinsic
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "OrderRequestHeader")]
    public class OrderRequestHeader
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Total")]
        public Total Total { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ShipTo")]
        public ShipTo ShipTo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BillTo")]
        public BillTo BillTo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Shipping")]
        public Shipping Shipping { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tax")]
        public Tax Tax { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PaymentTerm")]
        public List<PaymentTerm> PaymentTerm { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Comments")]
        public Comments Comments { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Extrinsic")]
        public List<Extrinsic> Extrinsic { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "orderDate")]
        public string OrderDate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "orderID")]
        public string OrderID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "orderType")]
        public string OrderType { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemID")]
    public class ItemID
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SupplierPartID")]
        public string SupplierPartID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "UnitPrice")]
    public class UnitPrice
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Money")]
        public Money Money { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Classification")]
    public class Classification
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "domain")]
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemDetail")]
    public class ItemDetail
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UnitPrice")]
        public UnitPrice UnitPrice { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description")]
        public Description Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UnitOfMeasure")]
        public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Classification")]
        public Classification Classification { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ManufacturerPartID")]
        public string ManufacturerPartID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ManufacturerName")]
        public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LeadTime")]
        public string LeadTime { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Extrinsic")]
        public List<Extrinsic> Extrinsic { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemOut")]
    public class ItemOut
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ItemID")]
        public ItemID ItemID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ItemDetail")]
        public ItemDetail ItemDetail { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tax")]
        public Tax Tax { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Comments")]
        public Comments Comments { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lineNumber")]
        public string LineNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "quantity")]
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "requestedDeliveryDate")]
        public string RequestedDeliveryDate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "requisitionID")]
        public string RequisitionID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "OrderRequest")]
    public class OrderRequest
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "OrderRequestHeader")]
        public OrderRequestHeader OrderRequestHeader { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ItemOut")]
        public List<ItemOut> ItemOut { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Request")]
    public class Request
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "OrderRequest")]
        public OrderRequest OrderRequest { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "cXML")]
    public class CXML
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Request")]
        public Request Request { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "payloadID")]
        public string PayloadID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "timestamp")]
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}

From there, I am creating a [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization) object and attempting to `Deserialize` the `XML Document` using the following below.

```
static void Main()
{
    string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "foo.xml");

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order));
    Order order = null;

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        order = (Order)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Normally when I convert an XML document to a class object, 
the XML documents haven't been so large, however because this one has multiple classes from what I can see,
 I don't understand how I can `Deserialize` the XML to the class object when there are multiple classes that have been generated.
I did see on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435260/use-multiple-namespaces-when-deserializing-with-net-xmlserializer) thread that maybe the answer to my question has to do with [Xml Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx)'s but I'm once again, not too sure.
The error that I'm getting is 
`An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll`
`Additional information: There is an error in XML document (3, 2).`

I used [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html) site to validate the XML, so I'm pretty sure that its got to the with the way I'm attempting to `Deserialize` it.

As you can see I'm trying to using the XmlSerializer like this

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order));
```

I realize this is incorrect for this as there are multiple classes that have been generated
Is there a way to make this one complete class?

Comment: Post your `foo.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is your xml is not well formed.  An xml file should have only one node at the root level.  You have Order with a bunch of classes inside Order that create multiple classes at the root level.  You order class shold look like the class below.  I only included a few of the children as an example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Order order = new Order() {
                credential = new Credential() { Domain = "MyDomain", Identity = "Me", SharedSecret = "I'm not Donald Trump" },
                from = new From() { Credential = new Credential() { Domain = "MyDomain", Identity = "Me", SharedSecret = "I'm not Donald Trump" } },
                to = new To() { Credential = new Credential() { Domain = "MyDomain", Identity = "Me", SharedSecret = "I'm not Donald Trump" } }
            };

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            XmlSerializer serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order));
            serialize.Serialize(writer,order);

            writer.Close();

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            Order readOrder = (Order)serialize.Deserialize(reader);


        }
    }
    public class Order
    {
        public Credential credential { get; set; }
        public From from { get; set; }
        public To to { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Credential")]
    public class Credential
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Identity")]
        public string Identity { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "domain")]
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SharedSecret")]
        public string SharedSecret { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "From")]
    public class From
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Credential")]
        public Credential Credential { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "To")]
    public class To
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Credential")]
        public Credential Credential { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Sender")]
    public class Sender
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Credential")]
        public Credential Credential { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UserAgent")]
        public string UserAgent { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Header")]
    public class Header
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "From")]
        public From From { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "To")]
        public To To { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sender")]
        public Sender Sender { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Money")]
    public class Money
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "currency")]
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Total")]
    public class Total
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Money")]
        public Money Money { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Name")]
    public class Name
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Country")]
    public class Country
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "isoCountryCode")]
        public string IsoCountryCode { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "PostalAddress")]
    public class PostalAddress
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DeliverTo")]
        public string DeliverTo { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Street")]
        public List<string> Street { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "State")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PostalCode")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Country")]
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "CountryCode")]
    public class CountryCode
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "isoCountryCode")]
        public string IsoCountryCode { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TelephoneNumber")]
    public class TelephoneNumber
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CountryCode")]
        public CountryCode CountryCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "AreaOrCityCode")]
        public string AreaOrCityCode { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Phone")]
    public class Phone
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TelephoneNumber")]
        public TelephoneNumber TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Fax")]
    public class Fax
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TelephoneNumber")]
        public TelephoneNumber TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Address")]
    public class Address
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
        public Name Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PostalAddress")]
        public PostalAddress PostalAddress { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Phone")]
        public Phone Phone { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fax")]
        public Fax Fax { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "addressID")]
        public string AddressID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "isoCountryCode")]
        public string IsoCountryCode { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ShipTo")]
    public class ShipTo
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Address")]
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BillTo")]
    public class BillTo
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Address")]
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Description")]
    public class Description
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ShortName")]
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Shipping")]
    public class Shipping
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Money")]
        public Money Money { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description")]
        public Description Description { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "trackingDomain")]
        public string TrackingDomain { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "trackingId")]
        public string TrackingId { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TaxableAmount")]
    public class TaxableAmount
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Money")]
        public Money Money { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TaxAmount")]
    public class TaxAmount
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Money")]
        public Money Money { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "TaxDetail")]
    public class TaxDetail
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TaxableAmount")]
        public TaxableAmount TaxableAmount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TaxAmount")]
        public TaxAmount TaxAmount { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description")]
        public Description Description { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "category")]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "percentageRate")]
        public string PercentageRate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "purpose")]
        public string Purpose { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Tax")]
    public class Tax
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Money")]
        public Money Money { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description")]
        public Description Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "TaxDetail")]
        public TaxDetail TaxDetail { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DiscountPercent")]
    public class DiscountPercent
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "percent")]
        public string Percent { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Discount")]
    public class Discount
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "DiscountPercent")]
        public DiscountPercent DiscountPercent { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "PaymentTerm")]
    public class PaymentTerm
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Discount")]
        public Discount Discount { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "payInNumberOfDays")]
        public string PayInNumberOfDays { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Comments")]
    public class Comments
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Extrinsic")]
    public class Extrinsic
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "OrderRequestHeader")]
    public class OrderRequestHeader
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Total")]
        public Total Total { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ShipTo")]
        public ShipTo ShipTo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "BillTo")]
        public BillTo BillTo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Shipping")]
        public Shipping Shipping { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tax")]
        public Tax Tax { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PaymentTerm")]
        public List<PaymentTerm> PaymentTerm { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Comments")]
        public Comments Comments { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Extrinsic")]
        public List<Extrinsic> Extrinsic { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "orderDate")]
        public string OrderDate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "orderID")]
        public string OrderID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "orderType")]
        public string OrderType { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemID")]
    public class ItemID
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SupplierPartID")]
        public string SupplierPartID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "UnitPrice")]
    public class UnitPrice
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Money")]
        public Money Money { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Classification")]
    public class Classification
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "domain")]
        public string Domain { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemDetail")]
    public class ItemDetail
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UnitPrice")]
        public UnitPrice UnitPrice { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Description")]
        public Description Description { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UnitOfMeasure")]
        public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Classification")]
        public Classification Classification { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ManufacturerPartID")]
        public string ManufacturerPartID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ManufacturerName")]
        public string ManufacturerName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "LeadTime")]
        public string LeadTime { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Extrinsic")]
        public List<Extrinsic> Extrinsic { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ItemOut")]
    public class ItemOut
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ItemID")]
        public ItemID ItemID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ItemDetail")]
        public ItemDetail ItemDetail { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Tax")]
        public Tax Tax { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Comments")]
        public Comments Comments { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lineNumber")]
        public string LineNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "quantity")]
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "requestedDeliveryDate")]
        public string RequestedDeliveryDate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "requisitionID")]
        public string RequisitionID { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "OrderRequest")]
    public class OrderRequest
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "OrderRequestHeader")]
        public OrderRequestHeader OrderRequestHeader { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ItemOut")]
        public List<ItemOut> ItemOut { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Request")]
    public class Request
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "OrderRequest")]
        public OrderRequest OrderRequest { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "cXML")]
    public class CXML
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Request")]
        public Request Request { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "payloadID")]
        public string PayloadID { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "timestamp")]
        public string Timestamp { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "lang", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, I read your answers all the time and quite like them, so thank you, second, when deserialising the XML to an object, will I need to create multiple classes like the above to match each part of the XML?

Comment: Just the root element must be single xml tag.  So the root class must be one class (not an array).  The class can contain items that do not get serialized.  Private properties are ignored for serialization.

Comment: Interesting, so I can indeed create the Order class like a normal class with all the properties from the XML, and the root element is the first property from the XML

Comment: Root element is Order.  You serialize/deserialize the class Order.

Comment: Actually the public class order is what I added in hope that it would help it deserialise, the element that was first from what I can remember was credential, so I should add it above there correct?

Comment: Yes.  Usually to test serialization I create a class with test data and then serialize to create xml.  The I compare my xml results with xml file I'm trying to deserialize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180768/discussion-between-andrewe-and-jdweng).

Comment: I updated code to give working example.  Only change I made was the properties in Order needed to be made public.  Also note the tags in the XML and classes are case sensitive.  To change case the directives in square brackets will change from capital/lower case when class is different from xml.

Comment: Thank you very much, I ended up figuring it out basically using what you mentioned above, our code looks almost the same :)